# Google Calendar API, PHP, getting refresh token fails

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to use Google Calendar API in PHP to access one central account. The idea is that other users can add events to this central account (they don't have to be logged in Google account) so I would like to have permanent access to the account.

Firstly, I've done [Quickstart tutorial on Google's webpage](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php). I logged in my account and everything was working for some time. Later, my access token expired and now, `$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());` throws LogicException: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken. I found out that `$client->getRefreshToken()` returns null.

Here you can see my whole code to get Google Client:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setScopes(implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR) ) );
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/../config/client_secret.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$credentialsPath = __DIR__ . '/../config/calendar-php-quickstart.json';
$accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

// Refresh the token if it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using DalmTo's tutorial with regard to [Calendar API and service accounts](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/).

This is the refresh token implementation from her guide:

```
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {    
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the following code :

```
                   // Refresh the token if it's expired.
                    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                        // save refresh token to some variable
                        $refreshTokenSaved = $client->getRefreshToken();

                        // update access token
                        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refreshTokenSaved);

                        // pass access token to some variable
                        $accessTokenUpdated = $client->getAccessToken();

                        // append refresh token
                        $accessTokenUpdated['refresh_token'] = $refreshTokenSaved;

                        // save to file
                        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessTokenUpdated));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my code that I finally got to work. I'm using a front end web app to get the initial authorization and then passing that code to a php web service to store in the dbase for later use.

```
  <?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/**
class to provide google calendar api functions.
returns information to mobile web app in json format
**/
class Calendar
{

    private $client;
    private $clientsecretgoogle = '{input secret here}';
    private $clientIDgoogle = '{input client ID here}';
    private $objDatabase;
    private $queryParams;
    private $params;

    public function __construct($params)
    {

        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setClientId($this->clientIDgoogle);
        $this->client->setClientSecret($this->clientsecretgoogle);
        $this->client->setAccessType('offline'); //this seems to be important for refresh tokens to update
        $this->objDatabase = new Database();//connect to dbase
        $this->params=$params;

    }

    public function getAuthorizationRefreshTokensGoogle($authCode, $userID)
    {

        /*
        Get access_token and refresh token from returned auth code
        I'm getting this on the front end and then storing in dbase table
        Could have used the basic php library here but this worked so I stuck with it
        */
        $oauth_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?code=' . $authCode . '&client_secret=' . $this->clientsecretgoogle . '&client_id=' . $this->clientIDgoogle . '&redirect_uri=postmessage&grant_type=authorization_code';
        //using curl
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $oauth_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $return = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        $return = json_decode($return);
        // You can dump the vars to see the object
        //var_dump($return);

        //insert into table for later retrieval
         $strSQL = "insert ignore into tbloauth(oauth_usr_id,oauth_vendor,oauth_token,oauth_refresh_token,oauth_token_expire)VALUES
              (?,?,?,?,?)";
        //check for existence of refresh token in response
        //if not there then replace only the access_token
        //if there then replace access, refresh
        if(!$return->refresh_token){
            $strSQL .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE oauth_token=VALUES(oauth_token), oauth_token_expire=VALUES(oauth_token_expire)";
        }else{
            $strSQL .= "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE oauth_token=VALUES(oauth_token),oauth_refresh_token=VALUES(oauth_refresh_token), oauth_token_expire=VALUES(oauth_token_expire)";
         }
        //translate expire time NOW + 3600
        $expire = (time() + $return->expires_in);
        if (!$return->refresh_token) {
            $return->refresh_token = '';
        }

        $this->queryParams = array($userID, 'google', $return->access_token, $return->refresh_token, $expire);
        $this->objDatabase->insertQuery($strSQL, $this->queryParams);

        //you should now have a record now containing the access_token,refresh token, expire date

    }

   /*

   List calendars
   */
    function listCalendarsGoogle()
    {

        //1. Get tokens from database for the current user
        $result=$this->getUserAccessToken($this->params['usr_id'],'google');
        //2. Set access token with returned results
        $this->client->setAccessToken(json_encode($result[0]));

        //check for expired token and refresh if necessary
        if($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $this->client->refreshToken($result[0]['oauth_refresh_token']);
            $access_token = $this->client->getAccessToken();
            $strSQL="update tbloauth set oauth_token=? where oauth_vendor='google' and oauth_usr_id=? limit 1";
            $this->queryParams=array($access_token,$this->params['usr_id']);
            $this->objDatabase->updateQuery($strSQL,$this->queryParams);

        }

        //3.init calendar 
        $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);

        //4. list calendars of primary
        $calendarList = $calendar->calendarList->listCalendarList('primary');


        return json_encode($calendarList);


    }
    /**
    get access token for vendor(google in this case) using usr_id of user
    which is passed to the class from the web app

    */
    public function getUserAccessToken($usr_id,$vendor){

        $strSQL="select tbloauth.*,oauth_token as access_token,oauth_refresh_token as refresh_token from tbloauth where oauth_usr_id=? and oauth_vendor=? ";
        $this->queryParams=array($usr_id,$vendor);
        //echo $this->objDatabase->parms($strSQL,$this->queryParams);
        $aResult=$this->objDatabase->selectQuery($strSQL,$this->queryParams);
        $aResult[0]['client_id']=$this->clientIDgoogle;
        $aResult[0]['client_secret']=$this->clientsecretgoogle;
        return $aResult;


    }
    /**
    Insert Event into google using event info posted by web app

    */
    public function insertEventGoogle(){

        $result=$this->getUserAccessToken($this->params['usr_id'],'google');
        $this->client->setAccessToken(json_encode($result[0]));
        //check if expired
        //if expired then fetch new token with current token
        //update dbase with new token
        //this would be cleaner separated into another method
        //called before each list or insert calendar function

        if($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $this->client->refreshToken($result[0]['oauth_refresh_token']);
            $access_token = $this->client->getAccessToken();
            $strSQL="update tbloauth set oauth_token=? where oauth_vendor='google' and oauth_usr_id=? limit 1";
            $this->queryParams=array($access_token,$this->params['usr_id']);
            $this->objDatabase->updateQuery($strSQL,$this->queryParams);

        }

        //init calendar 
        $calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->client);
        //event info
        $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
            'summary' => $this->params['event_name'],
            'location' => $this->params['event_location'],
            'description' => $this->params['event_desc'],
            'start' => array(
                'dateTime' => date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($this->params['event_start_date'].' '.$this->params['event_start_time'])),
                'timeZone' => 'America/New_York',
            ),
            'end' => array(
                'dateTime' => date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($this->params['event_end_date'].' '.$this->params['event_end_time'])),
                'timeZone' => 'America/New_York',
            ),
            'reminders' => array(
                'useDefault' => FALSE,
                'overrides' => array(
                    array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                    array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
                ),
            ),
        ));
        //calendar id - default primary
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        //insert event
        $event = $calendar->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
        //return confirm msg
        $msg=array('msg'=>'Event Created: '.$this->params['event_name']);
        return json_encode($msg);





    }
}
```

Hope that helps someone. The documentation was difficult to sort through.